# Freebsd page level premission with in a user space process

Tags: linker, freebsd

Is there a way in FreeBSD by which we can restrict few contiguous instruction pages to read and write to only to few data segment pages? Basically I am trying to restrict dynamically linked libraries to read and write only pages linked due to dynamically linked library and only few pages of the global data in the rest of the process address space.

Can this be done using linker directives or by modifying page level bits within the kernel?

Regards,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

You can set the protection level of pages (e.g. make them read-only) within the virtual address space of a process with [mprotect(2)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mprotect).